# error c2056: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

so this obviously isn't the real error, but i have no idea what the actual error is because the symptom is so vague. I'll just include the files here and you guys tell me where and what you think it might be causing the undeclared identifier error.

`system.h(66): error C2065: 'EntityManager' : undeclared identifier`

system.h

```
/*******************************************************************************
filename: System.h

Author:

Date: November 13, 2010

********************************************************************************/


#ifndef SYSTEM_H
#define SYSTEM_H

#include <string>
#include <memory>

//The interfaces for the framework elements.
#include "I_OS.h"
#include "I_Graphics.h"

//The derived interface elements tailored to the platform.
#include "Windows_module.h"
#include "D3D11_module.h"
#include "EntityManager.h"

// ** AUTHOR NOTE ** temporary until ini file reading is implemented
#define FULL_SCREEN false


/*******************************************************************************
Purpose: 
This will be the central object that is responsible for containing and 
systematically initializing, updating per frame, and shutting down ALL the objects 
responsible for the various internal workings of the framework. This will also 
serve as the nexus for all external entities to retrieve data, interface with engine 
elements, as well as interfacing between eachother.
********************************************************************************/

class System 
{
public:

    /* All framework elements and interfaces contain an Initialization context to be
    created outside, filled out, and passed into the Initalize function. This is to
    maintain polymorphic similar function declarations, while still having variable
    parameters */

    class InitializeContext
    {
    public:
        HINSTANCE hinstance;
    };

    System();
    ~System();

    bool Initialize(InitializeContext &);
    void Run();
    void Shutdown();

public:

    //pointer declarations of interface types for each framework element
    std::shared_ptr<I_OS> m_os;
    std::shared_ptr<I_Graphics> m_graphics;
    std::shared_ptr<EntityManager> m_EntityManager;
};


/* This will be the global pointer that all entities will use to access the
public interface pointers to the entire framework.

** AUTHOR NOTE ** : all entities should refer to the interfaces, and non platform
specific elements to maintain crossplatform compatibility, (if it can be avoided)*/
extern std::shared_ptr<System> g_System;

#endif
```

EntityManager.h

```
/*******************************************************************************
filename: EntityManager.h

Author: 

Date: October 27, 2011

********************************************************************************/

#ifndef ENTITY_MANAGER_H
#define ENTITY_MANAGER_H

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include "EntityBase.h"
#include "EntityList.h"

/*******************************************************************************
Purpose:
This wil be the object responsible for managing and updating all the various Entities
currently rendered in a scene. It reads from a scene file and dynamically creates instances
of the objects listed to be stored in a vector. these objects can be accessed individually
by either index or unique string identifier, or you can obtain a vector that contains
objects of the same class type. 
********************************************************************************/
class EntityManager
{
public:
    bool Initialize();
    bool Frame();
    void Shutdown();

private:
    BaseFactory m_factory;
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr<BaseEntity> > m_EntityList;
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseEntity> > m_EntityByNameList;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseEntity> > > m_EntityByClassList;
};

#endif
```

So is there anything wrong with these to be causing EntityManager to be undeclared? It's the only error in the output. Think you need anymore files and i'll include them.

Comment: Looks like a classic case of circular header file inclusions..does `EntityBase.h` or `EntityList.h` include `system.h`? BTW, there is no need to include `EntityManager.h` in `System.h`, just a forward declaration of `class EntityManager;` should be sufficient.

Comment: no actually neither do. Also, i did not know that about forward declaration, thanks for the tip

Comment: You need to go on searching recursively..i.e. you need to check the header files included by `EntityManager.h` to check whether they include `system.h`.

Comment: okay, actually, forward declaring only got me a bunch of use of undefined type errors :\ .

Comment: @Naveen: ah dang, you're right, EntityList includes and entity that includes an entity, that includes an entity, that includes system.h :( . But it really does require the use of system.h . might you have a suggestion to avoid the circular include?

Comment: Removing `#include "EntityManager.h"` from `System.h` and forward declaring `class EntityManager;` in `system.h` should solve it. Note that you need to do `#include "EntityManager.h"` in `system.cpp`. If it still gives errors can you post the updated code with exact error message?

Comment: @Naveen: alright, i forward declared it, and after fixing a couple other linking errors, it compiled just dandy. But since your comment is a comment, i have no answer to accept. at least a +1 i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally caused by the circular inclusion of header files. In your case, it looks like either `EntityBase.h` or `EntityList.h` includes `System.h`. The simplest way to solve this is to remove `#include "EntityManager.h"` from `System.h` and forward declaring `class EntityManager;` in `system.h`.  Note that you need to do `#include "EntityManager.h"` in `system.cpp`.

Comment: and an answer for you. Wish there was some way the compiler could pick up on it, rather than as undeclared identifier, but compilers aren't magic i guess.